# FormApp.getActiveForm() returns incorrect form id when called from form trigger which contains this function call

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I’m trying to automate work routines with google forms, php and mysql. I did the following software architecture.

There is the form named as S, it is the static one, since I created it manually using GUI. Form Sform has the form submit trigger which puts data into the my mysql database.

After that data is processed by the php script which finally calls google script, which is published as a web application.

This script gets get parameters and parses them, gets new processed data from my database and programmatically builds forms depending on the selected data, finally it adds a trigger to dynamically (programmatically) created form or forms (let's name them as Dform).

The problem is that the function FormApp.getActiveForm() which is coded in the trigger of programmatically created form returns form id of the static form (which is manually created).

Here the code of static form Sform submit trigger:

```html
function SaveData() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var email = formResponse.getRespondentEmail();
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  var workDay = null;
  var workFiles = null;
  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
    if (itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() == 'Pick the date of files you uploading') {
        workDay = itemResponse.getResponse().toString();
    }
    if (itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() == 'Choose log files to be uploaded') {
        workFilesIds = itemResponse.getResponse();
    }
  }

  var dbUrl = '...';
  var user = '...';
  var userPwd = '...';
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('select worker_id from in_workers where worker_name = ?');
  stmt.setString(1, email);
  var results = stmt.executeQuery();
  var worker_id = -1;
  while (results.next()) {
    worker_id = results.getString(1);
  }
  results.close();

  if (worker_id == -1) {
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO in_workers '
                                   + '(worker_name) values (?)', 1);
    stmt.setString(1, email);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
    var res = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
    res.beforeFirst();
    res.next();
    worker_id = res.getInt(1);
  }

  var fName = '';
  var fBlob = new Array(workFilesIds.length);
  for (var j = 0; j < workFilesIds.length; j++) {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(workFilesIds[j]);
    fName = fName + '\n\r' + file.getName();
    fBlob[j] = file;

    stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO test_dep_files '
                                   + '(worker_id, file_name, file_date, file_body) values (?, ?, ?, ?)');

    stmt.setString(1, worker_id);
    stmt.setString(2, file.getName());
    stmt.setDate(3, Jdbc.parseDate(workDay));
    stmt.setBytes(4, file.getBlob().getBytes());

    stmt.executeUpdate();
  }

  conn.close();

  GmailApp.sendEmail('...', 'Control workplace form completed'
                     , 'User ' + email + ' uploaded data on ' + workDay 
                     + ' file list: ' + fName, 
                     {attachments: fBlob, name: fName});
}
```

Here the code of script published as web application:

```html
function doGet(e) {
  var worker_id = e.parameter['worker_id'];
  var form_trig_func_name = e.parameter['form_trig_func_name'];

  var dbUrl = '...';
  var user = '...';
  var userPwd = '...';
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  stmt = conn.prepareStatement('select form_id from in_workers where worker_id = ?');
  stmt.setString(1, worker_id);
  var results = stmt.executeQuery();
  var form_id;
  results.beforeFirst();
  while (results.next()) {
    form_id = results.getString(1);
  }
  results.close();

  var form;
  try {
    form = FormApp.openById(form_id);
    var items = form.getItems();
    var l = items.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
      form.deleteItem(0);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    form = FormApp.create('Enter additional products data');
  }

  stmt = conn.prepareStatement('select fc_id, fc_name_sys, fc_date from test_dep_fc t1' 
    + ', test_dep_files t2 where t1.file_id = t2.file_id and fc_name_real is null '
    + 'and worker_id = ?');
  stmt.setString(1, worker_id);
  var results = stmt.executeQuery();
  results.beforeFirst();
  while (results.next()) {
    form.addTextItem()
      .setTitle(results.getString(2) + ' от ' + results.getString(3))
      .setHelpText(results.getString(1));
  }
  results.close();

  form_id = form.getId();

  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(form);
  var l = allTriggers.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) 
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
  allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  l = allTriggers.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction() === 'saveData' + form_trig_func_name) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
    }
  }

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('saveData'+form_trig_func_name)
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
  var form_url = form.getPublishedUrl();

  stmt = conn.prepareStatement('update in_workers set form_id = ?, form_url = ? where worker_id = ?');
  stmt.setString(1, form_id);
  stmt.setString(2, form_url);
  stmt.setString(3, worker_id);
  stmt.execute();
  conn.close();

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(form_id + '\n\r' + form_trig_func_name);
}
```

This is the code of dynamically (programmatically) created forms Dforms:

```html
function saveData2() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  var dbUrl = '...';
  var user = '...';
  var userPwd = '...';
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  var fc_names_real = '';
  var fc_ids = '';
  var fc_names_sys = '';

  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
    var fc_id = itemResponse.getItem().getHelpText();
    var fc_name_sys = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var fc_name_real = itemResponse.getResponse().toString();

    fc_names_real = fc_names_real + ' ' + fc_name_real;
    fc_ids = fc_ids + ' ' + fc_id;
    fc_names_sys = fc_names_sys + ' ' + fc_name_sys;

    stmt = conn.prepareStatement('update test_dep_fc '
                                   + 'set fc_name_real = ? where '
                                   + 'fc_id = ?');
    stmt.setString(1, fc_name_real);
    stmt.setString(2, fc_id);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
  }

  conn.close();

  GmailApp.sendEmail('...', 'Control workplace form2 completed'
                     , 'Product serial nums: ' + fc_names_real
                     + '\n\rProducts sys nums: ' + fc_names_sys 
                     + '\n\rProducts ids: ' + fc_ids
                     );
}

function saveData3() {
  the same code as for saveData2
  }
function saveData4() {
  the same code as for saveData2
  }
function saveData5() {
  the same code as for saveData2
  }
...
```

So the problem is that in saveData2 first code instruction returns wrong form id. It always returns form id of Sform.

Please help me with this, I'm ready to think that I have found a google forms bug.

Thanks a lot, Yaroslav

**EDIT 1**
hi @tehhowch, thank you, I did try, but, unfortunately, following code

```html
function saveData2(e) {
    //var form_id = e.source.getId();
    ...
```

returns wrong form id as well, it returns Sform id.

Comment: Use the event object, which contains the reference to the appropriate invoking Form... Also note that `getProjectTriggers` has a bug (reported in Apps Script issue tracker) and returns only the current user triggers.

Comment: hi, I tried and answered to you in EDIT 1 part

Answer (score 0):

Finally this issue was solved next day it was written here. The solution is as simple as it is stupid one.

1. In the script published as web application code I add following instructions after form creation code. I save trigger function name to its properties.

```
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty(
    'saveData'+form_trig_func_name, form_id);
```

2. Code to dynamically (programmatically) create forms Dforms was rewritten. When corresponding trigger fires I just take a formId in earlier saved property value.

```
function saveData2(e) {
  //var form_id = e.source.getId();
  var form_id = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('saveData2');
  saveDataAll (form_id, 2);
}
function saveData3() {
  var form_id = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('saveData3');
  saveDataAll (form_id, 3);
}
function saveData4() {
  var form_id = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('saveData4');
  saveDataAll (form_id, 4);
}
function saveData5() {
  var form_id = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('saveData5');
  saveDataAll (form_id, 5);
}
function saveData6() {
  var form_id = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('saveData6');
  saveDataAll (form_id, 6);
}
function saveData7() {
  var form_id = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('saveData7');
  saveDataAll (form_id, 7);
}
function saveData8() {
  var form_id = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('saveData8');
  saveDataAll (form_id, 8);
}
function saveData9() {
  var form_id = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('saveData9');
  saveDataAll (form_id, 9);
}
function saveData10() {
  var form_id = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('saveData10');
  saveDataAll (form_id, 10);
}
function saveData11() {
  var form_id = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('saveData11');
  saveDataAll (form_id, 11);
}


function saveDataAll (form_id, saveData)
{
  var form = FormApp.openById(form_id);
  ...
```

I have not more then ten users of this functional and such workaround works for me. So the problem is closed.